# Should "stranger" be capitalized when addressing someone in an email?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

I am emailing someone who I don't know the name of, so I am addressing the email with "Hello Stranger". Should I capitalize "stranger"?

Thanks

Comment: No more than you'd capitalise *"Wotcha Mate!"* in BrE, or *"Wassup Brother?"* in AAVE.

Comment: One would hope that if you're using this greeting it means you are enough of a friend with the other party that it doesn't really matter whether you capitalize or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should capitalize it. *Stranger* itself obviously isn't the name of the person, but you're using it as a replacement for his/her name, thus *stranger* should be capitalized.

Additionally, you could say this is an issue of respect. Since you don't know them personally, it's better to show respect by capitalizing whatever word you're using (because no one on this earth is insulted by being shown respect).

Comment: If you do not know the other party you should not use this greeting.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree. I wouldn't dare do this.